# How to handle XML in body of a post request with a Wicket page

Tags: java, xml, post, wicket

I've tried to set up a page in [Wicket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket) (extending org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage) to receive an HTTP post request containing an XML document in the body that is coming from a third-party service provider ([CRE Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayLeap), a credit card gateway) and when I access the request input stream like this:

```
getWebRequest().getHttpServletRequest().getInputStream();
```

... the stream always has zero bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but something might have already read the bytes and turned it into an object.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing. Going to try to run it through the debugger today.

Answer (score 3):

After a little debugging, I got to the bottom of this. The InputStream is being consumed by the creation of a PageParameters object. The following method extracts the xml as a string from PageParameters:

```
private String getXmlFromPageParameters(PageParameters params) {
// There should be a single PageParam whose key is the 
// XML document (up to the 1st =) and whose value is 
// either empty or the rest of the xml document after 
// the 1st =.
String xml = null;
for (String key : params.keySet()) {
    xml = key;
    if (params.getString(key) != null && !"".equals(params.getString(key))) {
        xml = xml + "=" + params.getString(key);
    }
}
return xml;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on the Content-Type of the incoming stream. Browsers (e.g. Chrome) by default set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded or similar which results in the PageParameters being loaded.

Overriding the default with the enctype attribute on the form element (e.g. to say text/xml) results in the body of the request being available via the InputStream (although it will still probably be URLEncoded).

Using a programmatic source (e.g. Apache DefaultHttpClient) and setting the Content-Type header also lets you choose whether the body of the post is in PageParameters or the InputStream.

**Wicket 1.5 Update**

In Wicket 1.5 the PageParameters is empty. Instead call

```
RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getPostParameters().getParameterValue("xml")
```